# How attackers bypass windows smart screen

Tags: certificates, malware, windows, code-signing

I'm curious to how attackers gain access to valid EV certificates that bypass windows smart screen (for malware delivery/execution) or how they sign these malicious software(s) without access to EV certs. I'm aware of methods to use droppers to utilize windows scripting.

What services actually work?

Comment: adversaries usually either steal valid certs or buy them.

Comment: How would an attacker buy EV certs? Most services require identity authentication, possibly by identity theft? Or are there services that provide certs with no strings attached?

Comment: https://stripe.ian.sh/